# Zip Code validation using MVC2 in asp.net mvc

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter AccountZip Code!")]
            [RegularExpression(@"/(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/", ErrorMessage = " Zip code must be 5 characters length")] 
            public string AccountZip { get; set; }
```

I did regularexpression for Zip code validation I am getting this Error Message

parsing "/(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/" - Not enough )'s.

Can any body help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Your regex looks like it was pulled from a javascript sample.  Try this:

```
@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$"
```

Comment: Think you should anchor it with `^` and `$`.

Comment: Not really necessary for .NET validators (since they validate against the entire string anyway), but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 4):

You need one more ( at the end as follows:

```
RegularExpression(@"/(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?)$/"
```

Comment: how to restrict to enter only Numbers? not characters in to that field?

Comment: The RegEx will only match if the field contains numbers, but if you want to prevent the user from entering anything other than numbers, then you need JavaScript of JQuery code on the client side to stop them.  Here is a link to a plugin that might help. http://igorgladkov.com/jquery/validator.html

Comment: Leons I dont think we need Client Side code to stop them. here is the thing i updated my code with this code.. @"\b(0?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\b" this will allow only numbers..thanks for your time

Comment: @user300485: wouldn't that allow "this text too 00000"? Might need to anchor it with `^$` instead of `\b` (unless these attributes do that for you)

Answer (score 1):

Great job @"\b(0?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\b" actually works and validates both numeric and length